# rankN type equivalent for mypy in python

Tags: python, haskell, types, mypy

In Haskell we can use rankN types like so:

```hs
rankN :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
rankN f = (f 1, f 1.0)
```

Is the same thing possible in python with mypy?

I tried the following code in python 3.10.2 with mypy 1.7.1:

```py
I = TypeVar("I", int, float)


def rankN(f: Callable[[I], I]) -> tuple[int, float]:
    return (f(1), f(1.0))
```

This produces the following errors, implying that `f` is specializing to `float`:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "tuple[float, float]", expected "tuple[int, float]")  [return-value]
Argument 1 has incompatible type "float"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
```

I'm not necessarily expecting this to work since the magic syntax in the Haskell case is the nested `forall`, but I don't know if there is a similar way to convey this to mypy if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not familiar with mypy, but my guess is that you can (and must) represent this as a protocol with a generic method, in order to scope the type variable to be per method call, rather than per invocation of `rankN`.

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

class UnaryNumeric(Protocol):
    I = TypeVar("I", int, float)
    def __call__(self, input: I) -> I:
        pass

def rankN(f: UnaryNumeric) -> tuple[int, float]:
    return (f(1), f(1.0))
```

Now `rankN(lambda x: abs(x))` is accepted, while `rankN(lambda x: str(x))` is rejected. I was surprised that `rankN(lambda x: x / 2)` is also accepted, since `int` isn’t really a subtype of `float`, but I guess it [floats like a duck](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duck_type_compatibility.html).

Comment: This solution is almost correct, you only need to move `I` definition outside the class (it should be on the module level). Your idea is fine: `I` should be resolved not in `rankN` context, but lower. When `I` is inside arguments, it's resolved to the most narrow possible solution, `float` in OP case. When it parametrizes only `__call__` but not the protocol itself, it's resolved for every use site independently.

Comment: @STerliakov: Why’s that? I just made it local without much thought, since it doesn’t need to be used elsewhere. This works in mypy 1.7.1, which I think is intentional—[PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) says “type variables follow normal name resolution rules”.

Comment: Wow, it's very surprising. Convention is to always define type variables in the module scope globally, I'm very surprised that this works. There are no examples in PEP484 that show usage similar to yours. TIL something new, thanks - I used to believe that this is forbidden, but it's just unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Python expert, but from such issues as [python/mypy#4395](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4395) it seems like this doesn't exist and probably never will.